# Android Studio/LibGDX game running out of memory

Tags: java, android, memory, libgdx, dispose

I'm trying to develop a simple game to learn a basic amount of Java. Everything seems to run great, but after a while I'll begin to start crashing. I think what's happening is I'm creating too many objects and running out of memory, but I'm not sure how to prevent this. I was wondering if anyone had any tips or could see where I'm making a mistake I would be glad to hear advice.

```
package com.colordash.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.TextureRegionDrawable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

import java.util.Random;

class GameScreen implements Screen {
    private final ColorDash game;
    private Texture backgroundTexture;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    // rby ryb yrb ybr bry byr

    private float screenWidth;
    private float screenHeight;
    private int leftPressedValue;
    private int rightPressedValue;
    private int measuredValue;
    private int neededValue;

    private float redHeight;
    private float blueHeight;
    private float yellowHeight;

    private Stage stage;

    private Texture centerDisplayTexture;
    Texture buttonLRed;

    private float time;

    int randomNum;

    public GameScreen(final ColorDash gam) {
        this.game = gam;
        time = 0;

        backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background2.png"));
        backgroundTexture.setWrap(Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat, Texture.TextureWrap.Repeat);

        // create the camera and the SpriteBatch

        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport()); //Set up a stage for the ui
        screenWidth = stage.getWidth();
        screenHeight = stage.getHeight();

        float buttonWidth = 3 * (screenWidth / 12);
        float buttonHeight = 4 * (screenHeight / 12);

        float buttonLower = 1 * (screenHeight / 3) - buttonHeight;
        float buttonMid = 2 * (screenHeight / 3) - buttonHeight;
        float buttonHigher = 3 * (screenHeight / 3) - buttonHeight;

        float col1 = screenWidth - 23 * (screenWidth / 24);
        float col2 = screenWidth - 1 * (screenWidth / 24) - buttonWidth;

        Random randomButtons = new Random();
        int buttonLocations = randomButtons.nextInt(6);
        if (buttonLocations == 0) {
            redHeight = buttonLower;
            blueHeight = buttonMid;
            yellowHeight = buttonHigher;
        } else if (buttonLocations == 1) {
            redHeight = buttonLower;
            blueHeight = buttonHigher;
            yellowHeight = buttonMid;
        } else if (buttonLocations == 2) {
            redHeight = buttonMid;
            blueHeight = buttonLower;
            yellowHeight = buttonHigher;
        } else if (buttonLocations == 3) {
            redHeight = buttonHigher;
            blueHeight = buttonLower;
            yellowHeight = buttonMid;
        } else if (buttonLocations == 4) {
            redHeight = buttonHigher;
            blueHeight = buttonMid;
            yellowHeight = buttonLower;
        } else if (buttonLocations == 5) {
            redHeight = buttonMid;
            blueHeight = buttonHigher;
            yellowHeight = buttonLower;
        }

        // red 1
        // blue 2
        // yellow 4

        int[] combinations = new int[6];
        combinations[0] = 2; // red red
        combinations[1] = 3; // red blue
        combinations[2] = 4; // blue blue
        combinations[3] = 5; // yellow red
        combinations[4] = 6; // yellow blue
        combinations[5] = 8; // yellow yellow

        leftPressedValue = 0;
        rightPressedValue = 0;
        measuredValue = 0;

        Random rn = new Random();
        int randomNum = rn.nextInt(6);
        if (ColorDash.lastRandomNumber == randomNum) {
            randomNum = rn.nextInt(6);

        }
        neededValue = combinations[randomNum];

        if (neededValue == 2) {
            centerDisplayTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("redBig.png"));
        } else if (neededValue == 3) {
            centerDisplayTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("purple.png"));
        } else if (neededValue == 4) {
            centerDisplayTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blueBig.png"));
        } else if (neededValue == 5) {
            centerDisplayTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("orange.png"));
        } else if (neededValue == 6) {
            centerDisplayTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("green.png"));
        } else if (neededValue == 8) {
            centerDisplayTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bigyellow.png"));
        }

        // center display
        TextureRegion centerDisplayTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(centerDisplayTexture);
        TextureRegionDrawable centerDisplayTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(centerDisplayTextureRegion);

        Button centerDisplay = new Button(centerDisplayTexRegionDrawable);
        centerDisplay.setSize(screenHeight / 2, screenHeight / 2);
        centerDisplay.setPosition(screenWidth / 2 - (screenHeight / 2) / 2, screenHeight / 2 - (screenHeight / 2) / 2);
        stage.addActor(centerDisplay);

        // red buttons
        Texture redButtonTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("redright.png"));
        TextureRegion redButtonTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(redButtonTexture);
        TextureRegionDrawable redButtonTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(redButtonTextureRegion);

        Button buttonLRed = new Button(redButtonTexRegionDrawable);
        buttonLRed.setSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        buttonLRed.getStyle().up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("redleft.png"))));
        //buttonLRed.getStyle().down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("redleft.png"))));
        buttonLRed.setPosition(col1, redHeight);

        Button buttonRRed = new Button(redButtonTexRegionDrawable);
        buttonRRed.setSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        buttonRRed.getStyle().up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("redright.png"))));
        //buttonRRed.getStyle().down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("redright.png"))));
        buttonRRed.setPosition(col2, redHeight);

        buttonLRed.addListener(new InputListener() {@Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            leftPressedValue = 1;
        }@Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            leftPressedValue = 1;
            return true;
        }
        });
        buttonRRed.addListener(new InputListener() {@Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            rightPressedValue = 1;
        }@Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            rightPressedValue = 1;
            return true;
        }
        });

        stage.addActor(buttonLRed);
        stage.addActor(buttonRRed); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.

        // blue buttons
        Texture blueButtonTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blue.png"));
        TextureRegion blueButtonTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(blueButtonTexture);
        TextureRegionDrawable blueButtonTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(blueButtonTextureRegion);

        Button buttonLBlue = new Button(blueButtonTexRegionDrawable);
        buttonLBlue.setSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        buttonLBlue.getStyle().up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blueleft.png"))));
        //buttonLBlue.getStyle().down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blueleft.png"))));
        buttonLBlue.setPosition(col1, blueHeight);

        Button buttonRBlue = new Button(blueButtonTexRegionDrawable);
        buttonRBlue.setSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        buttonRBlue.getStyle().up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("blueright.png"))));
        //buttonRBlue.getStyle().down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right.png"))));
        buttonRBlue.setPosition(col2, blueHeight);

        buttonLBlue.addListener(new InputListener() {@Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            leftPressedValue = 2;
        }@Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            leftPressedValue = 2;
            return true;
        }
        });
        buttonRBlue.addListener(new InputListener() {@Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            rightPressedValue = 2;
        }@Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            rightPressedValue = 2;
            return true;
        }

        });

        stage.addActor(buttonLBlue);
        stage.addActor(buttonRBlue); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.

        // yellow buttons
        Texture yellowButtonTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("yellow.png"));
        TextureRegion yellowButtonTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(yellowButtonTexture);
        TextureRegionDrawable yellowButtonTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(yellowButtonTextureRegion);

        Button buttonLYellow = new Button(yellowButtonTexRegionDrawable);
        buttonLYellow.setSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        buttonLYellow.getStyle().up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("yellowleft.png"))));
        //buttonLYellow.getStyle().down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("yellowleft.png"))));
        buttonLYellow.setPosition(col1, yellowHeight);

        Button buttonRYellow = new Button(redButtonTexRegionDrawable);
        buttonRYellow.setSize(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        buttonRYellow.getStyle().up = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("yellowright.png"))));
        //buttonRYellow.getStyle().down = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("yellowright.png"))));
        buttonRYellow.setPosition(col2, yellowHeight);

        buttonLYellow.addListener(new InputListener() {@Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            leftPressedValue = 4;
        }@Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            leftPressedValue = 4;
            return true;
        }
        });
        buttonRYellow.addListener(new InputListener() {@Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            rightPressedValue = 4;
        }@Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            rightPressedValue = 4;
            return true;
        }
        });

        stage.addActor(buttonLYellow);
        stage.addActor(buttonRYellow); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        //Start taking input from the ui
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
        ColorDash.lastRandomNumber = randomNum;

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, 0, 0, Math.round(screenWidth), Math.round(screenHeight));
        //game.font.draw(game.batch,toString().valueOf(randomNum),400,350);
        //game.font.draw(game.batch,toString().valueOf(ColorDash.lastRandomNumber),400,400);
        game.batch.end();

        // tell the camera to update its matrices.
        camera.update();

        float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        time += deltaTime;

        double timeSpeeedMultiplier = ColorDash.counter * 0.005;

        // tell the SpriteBatch to render in the
        // coordinate system specified by the camera.
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        game.batch.begin();
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); //Perform ui logic
        stage.draw(); //Draw the ui
        game.batch.end();

        measuredValue = leftPressedValue + rightPressedValue;
        if (measuredValue > 20) {
            measuredValue = 0;
        }

        if (time > (2 - 2 * timeSpeeedMultiplier)) {
            game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game));
            ColorDash.scoreFinal = ColorDash.counter;

        }

        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            if (leftPressedValue > 0 && rightPressedValue > 0 && measuredValue != neededValue) {
                game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(game));
                ColorDash.scoreFinal = ColorDash.counter;
            }
            if ((leftPressedValue > 0 && rightPressedValue > 0 && measuredValue == neededValue)) {
                ColorDash.counter++;
                if (ColorDash.counter == 15) {
                    game.setScreen(new GameScreenLevel2(game));
                } else {
                    game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
                }
                leftPressedValue = 0;
                rightPressedValue = 0;
                measuredValue = 0;
                ColorDash.scoreFinal = +((2 - 2 * timeSpeeedMultiplier) - deltaTime);

            }
        } else {
            leftPressedValue = 0;
            rightPressedValue = 0;
            measuredValue = 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // start the playback of the background music
        // when the screen is shown
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {}

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {}

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        backgroundTexture.dispose();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Memory leaks are happening when some object that should be garbage collected is still referenced by another long living object (for example a static object), this long living object is called a GC root. I'm not immediatly seeing any problems with your code, is it possible you have a memory leak in another class? Its also possible that the images are too big and you need to scale it down

Answer (score 2):

Every Disposable object you initialize in the constructor or `create()` must be disposed before the reference to this screen is lost. You can put all your `dispose()` calls into the screen's `dispose()` method, and call the screen's `dispose()` method from its `hide()` method, since you are not reusing screens.

Textures, SpriteBatches, and Stages are all Disposables.

But it is wasteful for you to throw away your screen and load another instance of the same screen, since it is loading all the same assets all over again. It would make more sense to make a method that resets the state of the gameplay-related stuff and use that instead of creating and setting a new screen.

By the way, `stage.act()` calls `begin()` and `end()` on its own internal SpriteBatch. It's wasteful to even let it have its own SpriteBatch, so you should pass your esixitng instance into the Stage constructor.

Comment: Is there anywhere you could direct me towards for resetting the state of gameplay/screen? I've been away from this project for quite a bit of time, but I've had some free time recently.

I did some analysis using the memory monitor and I did find that what was happening was on reloading the screen, it was calling the garbage collector, and eventually that was happening so frequently that the program couldn't keep up. So I think resetting my assets instead of reloading everything is the key here. 

Thanks again1

Comment: Resetting state is going to depend entirely on your specific case. Typically you would write a method that sets every applicable parameter to the value you want.  If the garbage collector is getting called frequently, that is a separate issue, like creating a lot of new objects somewhere in your game loop.

Comment: A lot of what you read about the garbage collector taking care of memory for you in Java doesn't apply to games, because OpenGL requires a lot of allocation of memory that is outside the control of the GC. Hence the need for dispose methods, and resulting memory leaks if you fail to dispose of something when you're done with it.

Comment: You can also use an observer pattern for your game objects. (Google "game programming patterns observer".) Each individual object in the game that needs to be reset can observe a game state observable object and react to that changing state.